# Cannot add new role in MVC5 Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I add 3 roles using my MVC application before. Now I cant add new role. When I debug I can see new role Id but the Role name is empty. How can I solve this problem?

I have 3 roles at the moment. User, Admin, Sales. Now I want to add Account role and cannot add.

**CONTROLLER**

```
// POST: /Roles/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
        {
            Name = collection["RoleName"]
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**CSHTML**

```
@model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole

<div class="container body-content">
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create Role</h2>
    @Html.ActionLink("List Roles", "Index") | @Html.ActionLink("Manage User Role", "ManageUserRoles")
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <p>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
            </div>
        </p>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only use viewModels in your view, but as you are using your view and object now, you should adjust your controller the following to use mvc roleManager (much easier):

```
// POST: /Roles/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IdentityRole role)
{
    try
    {
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        roleManager.Create(role)

        context.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jelle, The /Roles/Create was a auto genertaed so cshtml. Now is working.